# PictureBox Image Won't Update/Refresh

Tags: c#, winforms

I have an application that has a listbox, and a picture box.  What I need is for when the ListBox.IndexChanged event is struck, the PictureBox image needs to update or refresh.

EDIT: The first time I select something from the list, the image loads up, but when I select another item, the image doesnt update.

I have tried both with no luck:

```
PictureBox1.Refresh();
PictureBox1.Update();
```

In the background, when the ListBox1's Index is Changed I have a script running to go to a specific web page and take a screenshot depending on which item is selected in the ListBox and replace the current imageBox's image.  I was thinking that maybe I just wasnt giving it time to go and get the image, so I tried this as well with no luck:

```
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);
```

Here is what the application looks like:

[image]

Here is what is on the ListBox1.IndexChanged event:

```
Process myProcess;
myProcess = Process.Start("C:/users/bnickerson/desktop/script/RegScript.cmd");
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
myProcess.Close();
string imgLoc = "C:/users/bnickerson/Desktop/script/result/last.png";
pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(imgLoc);
pictureBox1.Update();
```

Comment: You would have to verify what that last.png image looks like when you load it.  Just guessing at a 3 second wait time isn't a very reliable way to do what you are doing.

Comment: This is woefully unreliable code, you have no idea how long that script takes or whether it even succeeded to do its job.  Using the Process.Exited event is a minimum requirement.  Image.FromFile() also puts a lock on the file so running the script again is going to make it fail, probably undiagnosably because you didn't check the Process.ExitCode property.  Lose the .cmd file, anything it does can be done in C# better.

Comment: I will update the code to make it more reliable once I can find out how to update the image.  I verified that the script is running and completed before the wait time is up.  It just doesn't update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Hans pointed out, the image file is locked until the returned `Image`-object is `Disposed`. Try this:

```
using (Process ExternalProcess = new Process())
{
   ExternalProcess.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\users\bnickerson\desktop\script\RegScript.cmd";
   ExternalProcess.Start();
   ExternalProcess.WaitForExit();
}

string imgLoc = @"C:\users\bnickerson\Desktop\script\result\last.png";
if (pictureBox1.Image != null) { pictureBox1.Image.Dispose(); }
using (Image myImage = Image.FromFile(imgLoc))
{
   pictureBox1.Image = (Image)myImage.Clone();
   pictureBox1.Update();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I implemented your code, and it still seems to not want to Update the image.  Once the first image loads, it stays there when I click on another option.

Comment: Are you sure the code is ran? Does the `myuImage` actually hold the image or is it null etc? Another option is to load all used images only once, and add reference to the class' root.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue where the image would not refresh to anew image regardless of methods called to try to force it.

For some reason only happened when the PictureBox was not set to "Dock:FILL"

My fix was to both dispose the image and to assign it to NULL and then apply the new cloned image as shown below.

```
Public Sub ApplyLastImage()
    If ScreenPicture.Image IsNot Nothing Then
        ScreenPicture.Image.Dispose()
        ScreenPicture.Image = Nothing
    End If
    ScreenPicture.Image = CType(LastImage.Clone, Drawing.Image)
    ScreenPicture.Update()
End Sub
```